# Determine matrix of inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ with standard inner product space. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ satisfies $\langle Ax, Ay \rangle= \langle x,  y \rangle$ for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $A$ is....  (triangle matrix, symmetry matrix, skew symmetry, diagonal, or orthogonal matrix?)

Actually I just learned about inner space product in linear algebra section. I am having no problem doing the exercise about it, but my friend gave me this problem. I read my textbook repeatedly, but didn't find any informations or example about matrix in inner product space form like it. Please, could you help me?

Comment: Show that $A^T A = I$.

Comment: Note that $\langle x, Cy \rangle = \langle C^T x, y \rangle$.